# Dynamic Content Loading with JQUERY

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm trying load a page dynamically with ajax.  I pass along refid that i use to get the page content.

All the information is stored in a custom attribute in the  tag.  There are 10+ links with their own values. RefID is very long.  Not sure if that makes a difference.

```
<a href="#dPage" title="More Info" data-theme="c" lat="{value}" lon="{value}" refid="CnRiAAAA_wO24Cpr6mCxuLDmiXYmWB8GoC5AqCllosAfNUZbkxD3QeiLlldSgGAxiwFpIlEbMx1JxuM6J6-uvFCDA9C-NfMVxBkT438ylOSWm11b2S74qXngL-wYH29sm4KX48762VjhYov9G2oOPM_iQJRjBBIQiNyeosXXee4kwXLMYBBtChoUkQrLBokVPKDcRLehvs2PLVmDv68" id="detailslink"></a>
<div data-role="page" id="dPage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Details</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
            <div id="detailspage">

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

--

```
    $('#detailslink').live('click', function() {
        $("#detailspage").html('');
        var placelat = $(this).attr('lat'); 
    var placelon = $(this).attr('lon');
    var refid = $(this).attr('refid');
        $.ajax({  
               cache: false,
               url: "mobile/getdetails.php", 
               dataType: "html",
               data: "&lat="+placelat+"&lon="+placelon+"&refid="+refid,
               success: function (data) {   
                    alert("Success");
                    $("#detailspage").html(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert(textStatus);
                }

            });
        //alert("done");

    });
```

This doens't work properly on the iPhone.  The content is returned and works fine in chrome, firefox, safari, android, but not iphone.

The iphone does not show anything.  It looks like it does make the call but nothing on the page.

Stuck on this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched my includes from

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a4/jquery.mobile-1.0a4.min.js"></script>
```

to

```
<link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.min.js"></script>
```

And now it works.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the success function is being called on the iPhone? Tried putting an alert in there to check? Just wondering if there's an error occurring that you're missing.

Edit: Add an error function to the call. If it's failing, you'll hopefully find out why.

[jQuery Ajax() method docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: I put an alert into success function and it was not triggered.  What do I do next?  Thanks

Comment: The refid is like a 50+digit token id. Not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Revised my answer. Hopefully, the error() handler will give up the reason.

Comment: I've added the error and updated the code in the post.  Nothing shows up in iphone.

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577298/jquery-ajax-post-not-working-on-iphone-and-android help?

Comment: I would have to try it.  It uses post.  can i use post same way as ajax?  I'm new to this so that post is a little confusing to me.

Comment: I tried playing with the path but that just broke content loading for all the browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you including the js file using a relative path? Is the php called getdetails.php or getDetails.php?

Comment: The getdetails.php is all lowercase.   I would assume that it wouldn't work in all other browsers if that was wrong.