# Android: Trigger AJAX function not working

Tags: android, ajax, jquery

I have an AJAX function I am building which makes a call on `scroll` or `click/touchtstart` to append some content to my HTML.  Everything works great for me in the desktop environment, both on click and on scroll events.  However neither of them work on my Android 2.3.7 HTC EVO or my Nexus 7 on Android 4.1.1.

Here is my click JavaScript event handler:

```
$('.loadMore').each(function() {

  //Set URL and start on the first page
  var self = this;
  var path2root = ".";
  var loc = window.location.origin;
  var url = loc + "/process.php";
  var subcategoryId = $(this).parent().attr('data-subcategoryId');
  var page = 1;

  // Build the updated URL
  $(self).bind('touchstart', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    page++;

    // AJAX function for processing JSON
    $.ajax({
      url: url + "?subcategoryId=" + subcategoryId + "&page=" + page,
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      dataType: "json",
      async: false,
      success: function (data) {
        var i = 0;
        for(i = 0 ; i < data.length; i++) {
          var articleId = data[i].articleResult.articleId;
          var title = data[i].articleResult.title;
          var subhead = data[i].articleResult.subhead;
          var image = data[i].articleResult.image;
          var response = "<td><div class='articleResult'><a href='" + path2root + "/article/article.php?articleId=" + articleId + "'><img src='" + image + "' width='120'/></a><br><h3><a href='" + path2root + "/article/article.php?articleId=" + articleId + "'>" + title.substring(0,25) + "</a></h3></div></td>";
          $("table tr td:nth-last-child(2)").after(response);
        };
      }
    });
  });
});
```

My scroll function is very similar, only I bind the event to a different element, and on scroll:

```
// Collecting scroll info
    $('.overthrow').each(function() {

     // SAME VARIABLES

      $(this).scroll(function () { 
        if ($(self).scrollLeft() >= parseInt($(document).width() - 50)) {    
            if (finished == 1) {
              page++;
              finished = 0;

              // SAME AJAX FUNCTION

            };
          };
      });
    });
```

Keep in mind this is a mobile optimized webpage, not a native PhoneGap app, and I am using regular jQuery 1.8.0, not jQuery Mobile or PhoneGap.

I had found [THIS](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827) issue over on Google Code in regards to Android 2.3 not receiving touchstart events very effectively, which led me to start building the on scroll function instead.

Comment: Is your intention to have the content auto-populate during scroll or when the $('.loadMore') element is clicked / touched?

Comment: Well, I was initially building it to populate on touch/click, but when that failed to work on my Android device, I started building an on scroll function.  I included both scripts because both work flawlessly on Desktop Chrome/Ffox, etc, but not on any of my Android browsers.

Comment: Take a look at my answer; it should solve your problem... remember to remove the scroll event if you intend on binding to only to click/touch event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to get the AJAX call functioning properly for the on scroll event.  I have abandoned the `click/touchstart` event all together as that seems to be buggy in Android.

For whatever reason, Android was not reading dynamic URL correctly when uploaded to the webserver:

```
var loc = window.location.origin;
var url = loc + "/process.php";
```

So when I was building my ajax call with the compiled URL:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url + "?subcategoryId=" + subcategoryId + "&page=" + page,
```

the `window.origin.location` was being misinterpreted.  Instead I needed to hard-code the location of my `process.php` file:

```
url: "process.php?subcategoryId=" + subcategoryId + "&page=" + page,
```

I discovered my solution through another SO post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577298/jquery-ajax-post-not-working-on-iphone-and-android)

The only catch being my code was working on iPhone, but not on Android.  If anyone knows the reason behind this, that would be great information to have.

Answer (score 1):

According to your link from [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=19827) the fix would be to include an `e.preventDefault()` at the start of your `touchstart` event like so:

```
$(self).bind('touchstart', function(e) { // include e as a reference to the event
    e.preventDefault(); // prevents the default behaviour on this element
    ....
});
```

The above works on my Android 2.X devices; I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I have updated my code with your suggestion, and am still not receiving anything in either my 2.3.7 device, or my 4.1.1 Nexus 7.  Tested in Chrome, Ffox, Dolphin Browser, and Native Android Browser...

Comment: Hmm... can you link to your testing page or a JSFiddle.net with your issue? Its hard to diagnose without seeing the underlying code.

Comment: I know... give me a bit, I will compile a jsfiddle page

Comment: Hey there, I just figured it out, it actually had nothing to do with my touch event, and more to do with my URL building.  Due to the nature of how Android was handling my `var loc = window.location.origin;` I had to hard code the document location.  Not optimal, but it works for now.  Thanks so much for the response, +1

More reading here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577298/jquery-ajax-post-not-working-on-iphone-and-android

Comment: Awesome - glad you got it working! Don't forget to post the answer to your question and accept it. Sounds like this may help a few people.